# How can I decrypt SAML with PHP?

Tags: php, security, saml, federated

I have an application that I'm trying to integrate with Federated Security -- specifically, Siteminder.  I'm using the PHP-SAML toolkit found here: https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml

I have the x509 cert included in the application, and all works well, until encryption is turned on in the Siteminder environment.  Once that was turned on, I was no longer able to log in -- I received this message: **Invalid SAML response: Cannot locate Signature Node**

I've been able to determine that the SAML assertion being sent to the application, from Siteminder, is encrypted.  I'm able to see the assertion (sample included below).  Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to decrypt that message, so that I can then parse and use in my application.

```
<Response xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
      Destination="{VALUE HERE}"
      ID="_076e8f69ec4adb3b72f0cc76570527222e37"
      IssueInstant="2013-01-15T18:18:48Z"
      Version="2.0"
      >
<ns1:Issuer xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
            Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity"
            >{VALUE HERE}</ns1:Issuer>
<Status>
    <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
</Status>
<ns2:EncryptedAssertion xmlns:ns2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                        Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
                        >
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
                <xenc:CipherData>
                    <xenc:CipherValue>{VALUE HERE}</xenc:CipherValue>
                </xenc:CipherData>
            </xenc:EncryptedKey>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>
{CERTIFICATE HERE}
</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
        <xenc:CipherData>
            <xenc:CipherValue>{VALUE HERE}</xenc:CipherValue>
        </xenc:CipherData>
    </xenc:EncryptedData>
</ns2:EncryptedAssertion>
</Response>
```

If anyone can help, that would be amazing.

Comment: hi. were you able to decrypt your xml? I am having the same issues as well

Comment: @GK123512648 Is a third-party library an option? Our SecureBlackbox library for PHP does the job, if you can install an extension on your server.

Answer (score 1):

To decrypt a SAML message you can extract some code of the [simplesamlphp](http://simplesamlphp.org/) libraries.

The function **_decryptElement** of the **lib/SAML2/Utils.php**, decrypts an message element:

The header of the function:

function _decryptElement(DOMElement $encryptedData, XMLSecurityKey $inputKey, array &$blacklist)

(Use an empty array for the $blacklist)

Check at:

http://code.google.com/p/simplesamlphp/source/browse/trunk/lib/SAML2/Utils.php#356

To build the DOMElement you can use this functions of the **lib/SimpleSAML/Utilities.php**:

**formatXMLString** and **formatDOMElement**

http://code.google.com/p/simplesamlphp/source/browse/trunk/lib/SimpleSAML/Utilities.php#1577

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [lightsaml/lightsaml](https://packagist.org/packages/lightsaml/lightsaml) library. In it's cookbook there's an entry on decrypting SAML Assertion http://www.lightsaml.com/LightSAML-Core/Cookbook/How-to-decrypt-Assertion/

It's done by deserializing XML into a Response data model object, loading your key pair credential, and calling a decrypt method on the EncryptedAssertion which returns the plain Assertion.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is an issue with the Onelogin PHP code - a similar issue has been [logged](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml/issues) and there is an identical one for the Ruby implementation.

**Update:**

If you are trying to get around this, you need to decrypt this with your certificate i.e. the one that's in the sp.xml metadata that you sent to the IP.

Never used Onlelogin but there would be examples in the [SimpleSAMLphp](http://simplesamlphp.org/) code.

Comment: It's a little too long and too detailed for a comment. Also, it appears to contain a solution. :)

Comment: Thank you. You mention decrypting with the certificate...any idea how I would go about doing that?  Or where I would look in the SimpleSAMLphp code?  Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry - not a PHP guru - try asking on the forum - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/simplesamlphp